# Merge pandas datagrame on one key with overlapping columns, chose first non-empty

Tags: python, pandas

Take these two dataframes:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3], 'some':[None, None, 1], 'else': [11,22,33]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'id':[3,4,5], 'some': [5,5,5], 'el': [333,444,555]})
```

I want to merge them on the `id` column but as you can see the `some` column would overlap on `id=3`. That means that running `a.merge(b, on='id', how='outer')` results in this:

```
   id  some_x  else  some_y     el
0   1     NaN  11.0     NaN    NaN
1   2     NaN  22.0     NaN    NaN
2   3     1.0  33.0     5.0  333.0
3   4     NaN   NaN     5.0  444.0
4   5     NaN   NaN     5.0  555.0
```

How can I have it just keep the `some` column with the first provided values i.e. 1 instead of 5 and no `_x` `_y` columns?

Comment: An expected output would clarify things a lot here.

Comment: expected output for the row with id 3 would be id: 3, some: 1, el, 333. The dataframe would not have any _x or _y suffixes as described above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you want one of two things: The simpler (but less likely) is that you just want the `'some'` column from `a`, in which case you can simply drop some['b'] before the merge:

```
a.merge(b.drop('some', axis=1))
```

Or, you want the value of `a['some']` if its non-null, otherwise use `b['some']`, in which case you can use `.fillna()`:

```
c = a.merge(b, on='id', how='outer')
c['some'] = c.some_x.fillna(c.some_y)
```

Comment: The merge with fillna is exactly what is needed here. now all I gotta do is write it into the function to drop the `_x` and `_y` columns :) Thanks!